# How to make bootstrap nav dropdown item active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar and I am trying to keep selected item active after page reload. I have this script below and It works fine for normal items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;

    $('ul.navbar-nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

    $('ul.navbar-nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

But when it comes to dropdown type of navbar items my code does not work. Here is my navbar.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="navbar-list">
    <li class="nav-item admin-menu">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('teams.index') }}">Takımlar</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown admin-menu">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Hakem Yönetimi
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('referees.index') }}">Hakamler</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('referees.index') }}">Hakem Atamalar</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item admin-menu">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('reports.index') }}">Haberler</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can i fix that issue ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to replace `.parent().` with `.closest(".nav-item").` or `.closest("li").`

Comment: closest() method works much faster than parents(), because it stops and returns result once it found a suitable ansector, whilst parents() collects all elements of DOM then filters them - it takes much more time

Answer (score 1):

Because `a` links in dropdown has parent different from `nav-item`, so "active" class is assigned to `dropdown-menu` class instead of navigation-bar item.

I think it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    $('ul.navbar-nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parents('.nav-item').addClass('active');
});
```

Also JQuery `parent` method searches only 1 parent level.

Comment: @Tartar does `route()` method return absolute url?

Comment: Yes it does return an absolute url. Something like http://dev.example.com/sampleroute

Comment: @Tartar I prepared [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2h10guw/1/) example with my code and your markup. Your generated link should be similar to browser location link (including protocol `http\https` and trailing slash) and you should handle trailing slash issue as well(when user typed url manually with or without slash) .